# Why is my vanity bathroom light not working?

Tags: wiring

My vanity light was switched out in my bathroom. Before that was done I was able to turn bedroom light on and then go in the bathroom and turn the vanity light on. Now after the new vanity light was installed I cannot turn the bathroom vanity light on when the bedroom light is on. The bathroom vanity light must be turned on first in order to have the two lights on at the same time.

Comment: Who did the switching out of the vanity light?   Was any other item replaced,ie., switches, etc?

Comment: Pictures of the wiring behind the new light as well as behind the bathroom light switch will probably help immensely. **Turn power off at the breaker** before opening any electrical boxes, and do _not_ disconnect any wires.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a simple case of mixing up the hot’s
You probably have at least or more black wires, one is a hot one goes to the bedroom one goes to the vanity. Some one mixed them up the hot and the bedroom go on one side of the switch. The vanity goes on the other.
So your bedroom switch is always hot and works with its switch and the vanity works on the bathroom switch.

There may be several more black wires at the switch but a minimum of 3 to power this simple circuit.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably not going to get someone here to be able to tell you why this happening without detailed pictures of your switch box wiring and your light box wiring- with the wires identified as to where they go.

To get that you will most likely need to get an electrician (or a friend who knows what they are doing) out to open up the boxes and identify what wires go where.

At which point, they should be able to understand what is going on and just fix it.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because it's not an answer?

Comment: @kyle this is a diy site and the issue is very simple, all the information needed was given. It is also a common diy error.

Comment: OK- In defense a simplified version- Question- someone changed a light and now it is not working as it used to. Answer- It was wired wrongly. Someone needs to look at the wiring and figure out what was done wrong- at that point they should be able to fix it. This is exactly what my answer above is saying.